# Sending a String in Javascript to java method in Play Framework

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, playframework-2.3

I'm working on a system for my university and I'm using the play framework to do that.
The Admin of this system sets a marker on a google map and I get the coordinates from that point.

Now I'm trying to pass this information to the server side, so that I might store these to Strings in a mySQL database. The only problem I have is passing the data from my String in javascript/JQuery to the java function.

I tried different solutions on the internet but some of them seemed outdated and I couldn't figure out how to do it.

I've only been programming in Java, Javascript, JQuery and PHP and have never used AJAX (like the $.get() methode from JQuery), but I think it might be pretty similar to what I know from PHP.

e.g. 
http://java.dzone.com/articles/jquery-ajax-play-2

I'd like to pass my String with a button click to my java function, so I can store it in my db.

I'm really confused about this.

I know I can use something like

`<a href="{@routes.Application.postMethod()}"> Send </>`

and then mention the function in the routes like

POST /post  controllers.Application.post();

but how do I pass my qjuery string?
and how do I store my String as a String in a java function like:

```
public static Result post(String Lat, String Lng){

???????????? EVOLUTION NEEDED  ?????

}
```

Thanks in advance I really need your help :)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you are doing a POST, since this can be done using a GET request.

As per this example:
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2/ajax#jsaction

We can see Play makes it easier using the jsAction tag.  Lets assume you have the following route:

```
GET     /admins/marker        Admins.marker
```

Then in your HTML, at the bottom you'd do something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#myButton').click( function() {
   var action = #{jsAction @marker(':latitude',':longitude') /}
   $('#result').load(
       action({latitude: '23', longitude: $('#longitudeField').val }), 
       function() {
           $('#content').css('visibility', 'visible')
       }
   )
   });
</script>
```

In this case, the request will be sent like (example):

```
GET /admins/marker?latitude=23&longitude=67
```

And then on your backend, you need the have to java fn to deal with that route.

Basically the javascript/jquery, is called when #myButton element is clicked, then we generate the route URL we are going to make a request to using jsAction, then we make using load to make a GET request.  You can change this to post too if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, man :)!

I never thought about that, must've overlooked this possibility.
Really good Idea.

Unfortunately I can not vote up your answer as I don't have enough reputation but I will as soon as I get more :).